# installing rvm - connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install `rvm`.
I'm using the folowing guide:
https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.10

When I try running, `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`, I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to get.rvm.io port 443: Connection refused`.

I tried opening in the browser https://get.rvm.io and I get the same error.
There is no firewall.
I tried using my cellular phone, also down.
I connected through a remote server using OpenVPN, also down.
Are there any other sources for `rvm`?

Comment: I can confirm that the site is down at the moment. Seems they are having a problem. I guess you will have to wait until they fixed it. Or you might take this as a sign to go with `rbenv` instead? What was your reason to close `rvm`?

Comment: i am setting up a computer at work and these are the requirements. Interesting that there be only one source, no mirrors